# Is there any way to retrieve a user's "Apps others use" Facebook privacy settings?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Background:

After thinking that I had managed to successfully navigate Facebook's gauntlet of privacy settings, I have fallen prey to yet one last unexpected hurdle.

My Facebook app allows users to post content to Facebook (status updates, photos, etc). It also allows users to browse and view the same content of others who are users of the same app.   Even if two users (that are friends) have:

1. granted the necessary permissions (read_stream, user_photos, friends_photos, etc) to the app
2. successfully posted content with the sufficient visibility to Facebook through the app
3. the ability to see each other's posted content on Facebook itself

It is **still** possible that they can't read others' content through the app due to the "Apps others use" privacy setting which restricts what information others can see through the Facebook platform, despite that the user has specifically granted access to the app for that content (*ugh*).

This little quirk makes for a terrible user experience, so I would at least like to be able to detect that a user has this limitation in place an inform him/her accordingly.

My searches through the FQL tables have come up fruitless, but I'm holding out against hope... Is there a (undocumented?) way to retrieve the "Apps others use" settings for an authorized user via Facebook API method?

Comment: any progress on this?  I've run into a similar problem :\

Comment: Not on my end, I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Does the page http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/04/03/how-to-stop-your-friends-facebook-apps-from-accessing-your-private-information/ give you some help?

For going to that, is like in the image [image: Apps others use] : Go to the gear icon at the top right > Account Settings > Apps > Apps others use and then customize it.